# Looking for a good way to run two (dependent) tasks in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I need to run two tasks such that the second task is dependent on the action of first task. The first task is like download a file and second task performs some action on the downloaded file. For this, I've created two AsyncTasks A and B.

One option I have is to just merge the two tasks and have just one AsyncTask instead of two.

But I'm figuring out the options that I have if I don't want to merge the two tasks.

What I cannot do is to call one task and then directly call another task from my activity, for obvious reasons (because the code will call AsyncTask 2 before AsyncTask 1 is over which is running in the background).

Another option is to call the AsyncTask A, and then in the `onPostExecute` method of AsyncTask A, call AsyncTask B so that B will run only after the `doInBackground` portion of A is over. So, this is basically calling task from within another task.

Is there any other better way of doing this?

Is there a way by which I can know in my calling activity when the AsyncTask A is over (without blocking the UI thread) so that I can call AsyncTask B after knowing that the AsyncTask A is finished?

Comment: What android version is your app targeting to run?

Comment: [AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) can let you fine control the executor thread pool, unfortunately, it is only available since API Level 11.

Answer (score -1):

Of course!

Start both `AsyncTask`'s at the same time:

```
A.execute();
B.execute(A); // give B a reference to A
```

In your B.onBackground:

```
while(A.getState() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
 try{
  Thread.sleep(500);
 }catch(InterruptedException e){
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
}

// Your actual code here. This code section will only be reached if A was finished
```